# 400 error when trying to post hidden input data in prisma with sveltekit

Tags: typescript, orm, crud, prisma, sveltekit

I'm rebuilding a hangman app that I was making for a coding competition, and I'm really stuck, I keep getting a 400 Error - Bad Request response when trying to send my form to the postgreSQL db.

I'm basically using this [tutorial](https://www.prisma.io/blog/sveltekit-prisma-kvCOEoeQlC#set-up-a-prisma-client-singleton) to scaffold my CRUD operations, and I'm having trouble trying to update my Player table to update data in the db, so I have some leaderboard statistics to show in my app. I'm using cookies to find the player name (unique in the database). There's no documentation in Sveltekit about how to send data to the server with hidden inputs or for values you already have, the only way you send data seems to be through the form, but if I go into the inspect element tab and look at my payload for the bad request, it looks totally fine. Here's some code so I'm not just telling you about it,

myComponent.svelte:

```
<form method="POST" action="/random"> // sends the action to my /random server page
          <input value={wins} name="gamesWon" type="number" hidden />
          <input
            value={leastLettersGuessed}
            name="lowestGuesses"
            type="number"
            hidden
          />
          <button class="btn-dark">Go to leaderboard</button>
        </form>
```

I am getting my values from sessionStorage, but I don't think that should be the issue.
Here's my server file that is validating the data and sending it to the server,

random/+page.server.ts:

```
import prisma from "$lib/prisma";
import { fail, redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import type { Actions } from './$types';

export const actions = {
    // 1.
    default: async ({ request, cookies }) => {
        const data = await request.formData();

        let gamesWon = data.get("gamesWon");
        let lowestGuesses = data.get("lowestGuesses");
        let name = cookies.get('playerName');
       

        // 2.
        if (!gamesWon || !lowestGuesses) {
            return fail(400, { gamesWon, lowestGuesses, missing: true });
        }

        // 3.
        if (typeof gamesWon != "number" || typeof lowestGuesses != "number") {
            return fail(400, { incorrect: true })
        }

        // 4.
        await prisma.player.update({
            where: {
                name: name,
            },
            data: {
                gamesWon,
                lowestGuesses,
            },
        });

        //5.
        throw redirect(303, `/leaderboard`)
    }
} satisfies Actions;
```

I thought maybe I was sending the wrong names to the database, but I changed them and I was still getting the same error. Here's my data model:

```
model Player {
  id            Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name          String @unique
  gamesWon      Int    @default(0) @map("games_won")
  lowestGuesses Int    @default(27) @map("lowest_guesses")
  games         Game[]
}
```

It's a really frustrating error with very little info to go off of, please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `formData().get()` can only return `FormDataEntryValue` which is either a `File` or a `string`.

So in your code you will always get `string` as the type of the data and checking if it is of type `number` will always return false.

```
// always returns 400
if (typeof gamesWon != "number" || typeof lowestGuesses != "number") {
    return fail(400, { incorrect: true })
}
```

So instead if you use something like `parseInt` you can check if it is a valid number or not by checking the result with `isNaN()`

for example:

```js
let gamesWonString =  data.get("gamesWon");
let lowestGuessesString = data.get("lowestGuesses");

if (!gamesWonString || !lowestGuessesString) {
   return fail(400, { gamesWonString, lowestGuessesString, missing: true });
}

let gamesWon = parseInt(gamesWonString.toString())
let lowestGuesses = parseInt(lowestGuessesString.toString())

// 3.
if (isNaN(gamesWon) || isNaN(lowestGuesses)) {
    return fail(400, { incorrect: true })
}
```